# Scanning resolution

Tags: resolution, scanning

At http://www.scantips.com/basics07.html it is written:

*The motor in the 600x1200 dpi scanner can step in 1/1200 inch steps vertically. If we select 300 dpi, it will move four steps at a time vertically, and resample to 50% horizontally, to give a 300x300 dpi image.*

Can someone explain this? How resampling to 50% horizontally gives 300x300 dpi image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CCD is actually a single-line device.  In the example, the single line CCD scans at a horizontal density of 600 samples-per-inch. We can call this a scanline.  The hardware always captures 600 samples per inch (referred to as it's "optical density").

It moves vertically by an amount based on the motor and the settings. In the example, the motor moves 1/1200th of an inch for each increment, allowing for 1200 scanlines per inch vertically.

When you set the scanner to 300x300, it still captures a row of samples at a density of 600 samples-per-inch. It then uses software to resample (i.e., average or interpolate the original values to produce new ones).  The result is a scanline at a density of 300 samples per inch, by 1 scanline high.

Then the motor moves the CCD and takes another row.  By moving 4 increments of 1/1200 inch, the next scanline is 1/300 inch away. After moving the CCD 4 increments 300 times, taking a scanline each time, you now have a 300x300 image.

Comment: Sure, go for it

Comment: That works for me.

Comment: I have read that if we, for example, scan at uniform resolution we would have overlapping spots in one dimension. What is the rationale behind this? I am just talking hypothetically.

Comment: not sure what that means, but there are interpolation methods such as in interferometry that take advantage of multiple lower-res copies of a signal that are separated by some distance.

Comment: http://www.scantips.com/chap3c.html: " Digital photo images have "square" resolution, the same in both directions like 300x300 dpi, simply called 300 dpi. If we did try to scan film at 2400 dpi using a 1200x2400 dpi scanner, the carriage motor can indeed step at 2400 dpi vertically. However, all samples will overlap each other vertically by 50% because the 1200 dpi CCD cells are twice taller than 1/2400 inch in size. ". Not sure how samples would overlap when they would be rectangular in such case.

Comment: samples are always point samples and and pixels are not square and have no dimensions, so ignore that. http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos426/papers/smith95b.pdf

Comment: What would happen if scanning is performed at uniform resolution? How would scanned image look like?

Comment: the same, perhaps with slightly more detail. I say perhaps because interpolation can help resolve small details that are below the shannon-nyquist sampling limit

Comment: I was thinking at uniform resolution without interpolation. Would the image be distorted maybe?

Comment: no. It would be the same with (perhaps) slightly better resolution. It may not be better at all because the other manufacturer might be using interpolation to tease out more detail than one might expect from the lower (horizontal) resolution scanner.

Comment: But scanning is always performed at uniform resolution? In case of non-uniform resolution, then interpolation is used?